# How to implement a flip effect using Anuglar 2 animations?

Tags: angular, flip

I have been using pure css flip of cards in my project but this solution is not proper one. Can somebody present a flip in angular 2 on click of a button? I have found one in angularjs https://codepen.io/Zbeyer/pen/oXQrZg

```
    <div ng-app="cardFlipper" ng-controller="AppController">    
    <h1>Card Flipping AngularJS</h1>
    <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper" ng-click="flipCard()" ng-class="{'flipToFront':isCardRevealed, 'flipToBack':!isCardRevealed}">
            <div class="back" ng-class="{'face-hidden':hideBackFace}">
            </div>
            <div class="front" ng-class="{'face-hidden':!hideBackFace}">
                <h1>{{currentCard.title | uppercase}}</h1>
                <p ng-if="currentCard.icon">{{currentCard.icon}}</p>
                <br ng-if="currentCard.icon" />
                <img ng-if="currentCard.imageUrl" src="{{currentCard.imageUrl}}" alt="currentCard.imageAlt" />
                <p>{{currentCard.description}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div ng-if="currentCard && currentCard.source">
            <a ng-href="{{currentCard.source}}" target="_blank">Source</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <br />
    <br />


</div>
<style>
    /* CARD DIMENSIONS */
@width: 19em;
@height: 27em;
@shadow:1em 1em 2em #111111;
/* MIXINS */
.box-shadow (@string:@shadow) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: @string;
    -moz-box-shadow:    @string;
    box-shadow:         @string;
}


.box-sizing(@sizing:border-box) {
    -webkit-box-sizing: @sizing;
    -moz-box-sizing: @sizing;
    box-sizing: @sizing;
}

.border-radius (@radius: 0.5em) {
    -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
    -moz-border-radius: @radius;
    border-radius: @radius;
}

.top-perspective() {
        /*perspective*/
    -webkit-perspective:1000;
       -moz-perspective:1000;
        -ms-perspective:1000;
         -o-perspective:1000;
            perspective:1000;


}

 .flipped-transform-back () {
    /*transform*/
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
       -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
         -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
            transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipped-transform-front {
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
          -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
         -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
             transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flipper-transform(@transition: 0.4s) {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transition: @transition;
    -moz-transition: @transition;
    -o-transition: @transition;
    -ms-transition: @transition;
    transition: @transition;
}

.back-face-should-be-hidden() {

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* STYLE SHEET */

body {
    font-family: "myriad-pro", sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
    text-align:center;

    color:#D1D1D1;

    padding: 0;
    background-color:#333333;

    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

footer {
    text-align:center;
    padding:1em;
    a {
        font-size:1em;
        color:RGB(255, 208, 128);
    }
}


.flip-container {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: @width * 1.0;
    height: @height *1.0;
}   

.flipToFront {
    .flipped-transform-front();
}

.flipToBack {
    .flipped-transform-back();
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    .top-perspective();
    .flipper-transform();
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    .back-face-should-be-hidden();

    text-align:center;
    color:#333333;        
    padding: 0.25em;

    h1, h2, h3, a {
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }
}

.face-hidden {

    /*
        .face-should-be-hidden();
    */
}

.front, .back {
    /* hide back of pane during swap */
    overflow:scroll;

    display:inline-block;

    /* Card overlay eachother */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    /* Make Pretty */

    .box-sizing();
    .border-radius();    
    .box-shadow();
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color:#FEFEFE;
    .flipped-transform-front ();    
    .box-sizing();
     border:0.5em solid #FEFEFE;
    img {
        width:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height:auto;
        .border-radius();
    }
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    background-color:#EBEBEB;
    .flipped-transform-back ();

    background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/upfeathers.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    .box-sizing();
     border:1em solid #FEFEFE;


}

/* Media Queries */

/*
@highdensity: ~"only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)",
              ~"only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)",
              ~"only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2)",
              ~"only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)";
*/

@mobile:      ~"only screen and (max-width: 34em)";
@tablet:      ~"only screen and (min-width: 34em) and (max-width: 55em)";
@desktop:     ~"only screen and (min-width: 55em)";


@media @mobile {
    h1, h2, h3 {
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }

    .flip-container, .front, .back {
        width: @width * 1.0;
        height: @height *1.0;
    }
}
/*
@media @tablet {
        .flip-container, .front, .back {
        width: @width * 1.25;
        height: @height *1.25;

        h1, h2, h3 {
            font-size: 1.75em;
        }
    }
}

@media @desktop {
    .flip-container, .front, .back {
        width: @width * 1.5;
        height: @height *1.5;

    }
}*/

<script>
    angular.module('cardFlipper', [])
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {

    $scope.cards = [
    {
        title: "escheresque-dark",
        icon:"",
        imageUrl:"http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/escheresque_ste.png",
        description:"Sublte Pattern Source image below...",
        source: "http://subtlepatterns.com/escheresque-dark/"
    },
    {
        title: "dark sharp edges",
        icon:"",
        imageUrl:"http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/footer_lodyas.png",
        description:"Sublte Pattern Source image below...",
        source: "http://subtlepatterns.com/dark-sharp-edges/"
    },
    {
        title: "Grey Washed Wall",
        icon:"",
        imageUrl:"http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/grey_wash_wall.png",
        description:"Sublte Pattern Source image below...",
        source: "http://subtlepatterns.com/grey-washed-wall/"
    }
];
    $scope.currentCard = {};

    $scope.isCardRevealed = false;
    $scope.flipCard = function() {
        $scope.isCardRevealed = !$scope.isCardRevealed;
        if($scope.isCardRevealed) {
            $scope.generateCard();
        } else {

            $scope.currentCard = {};
            /*            setTimeout(function() {
//                $scope.isBackHidden = !$scope.isCardRevealed;
            }, 0.1 * 1000);
*/            
        }
        /*



        */
    }

    $scope.generateCard = function() {
        $scope.currentCard = {};
        var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * $scope.cards.length) + 0);
         $scope.currentCard = $scope.cards[index];
    }

}]);
</script>
```

Can somebody turn it into angular2 or implement something different?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

this demo using animation in Angular

```
import { Component, OnInit, trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div class="tp-wrapper">
      <div class="tp-box" (click)="toggleFlip()" [@flipState]="flip">
        <div class="tp-box__side tp-box__front">Front
        </div>
        <div class="tp-box__side tp-box__back">Back
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    .tp-wrapper {
      perspective: 800px;
    }

    .tp-box {
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 3rem auto;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: transform 1s;
    }
    .tp-box__side {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 100px;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 700;
      cursor: pointer;
      user-select: none;
    }
    .tp-box__front {
      background: #f30d36;
    }
    .tp-box__back {
      background: #23262d;
      transform: rotateY(179.9deg);
    }

    `
  ],
  animations: [
    trigger('flipState', [
      state('active', style({
        transform: 'rotateY(179.9deg)'
      })),
      state('inactive', style({
        transform: 'rotateY(0)'
      })),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('500ms ease-out')),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('500ms ease-in'))
    ])  
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {

  flip: string = 'inactive';
  constructor() {}

  toggleFlip() {
    this.flip = (this.flip == 'inactive') ? 'active' : 'inactive';
  }

}
```

Online demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/RZ1v9M?p=preview

Comment: It's not working on Mozzila, how can I make it work?

Comment: Tried @stephen-r-smith answer but still no luck.

Comment: This looks very similar, if not identical, to this example: [stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-flip](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-flip), which works great for me (the Plunkr refuses to run).

Answer (score 3):

This works great in Chrome, but in Safari/Firefox/Opera the flipped side content shows through (in reverse) when the front side is visible, and vice-versa, but you just need to add the browser specific backface-visibility styles.

So replace this:

```
 backface-visibility: hidden;
```

with this:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Then it displays in all browsers correctly.

Comment: for me, there is an odd behavior! https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-flip. Could u please look into this?

Comment: Checked it on Chrome, Safari, Firefox. Seems to like having a problem with Firefox.

Comment: @Warapitiya Thanks for the link to [stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-flip](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-flip). I made some minor style changes and it worked great for me! Tested fine on Chrome, Edge and Firefox v.61.0.2.

Comment: Still not able to flip it right in IE11. Facing same error while flipping and it shows reverse few of front box.