# Flip animation does't work on Firefox | Angular 4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, firefox

I'm using a flip animation on a div, it works fine on Chrome Browser but it doesn't work properly on Mozzila Firefox:

```
.tp-wrapper {
      perspective: 800px;
      -webkit-perspective: 800;
    }

    .tp-box {
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 3rem auto;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: transform 1s;
      transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    }
```

**Plunker:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZIrUhzFB7Gc8y5WgKnYy?p=preview

I tried using some -webkit on css but it doesn't seems to have effect.

Comment: May I suggest asking the original person who answered this in a different [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177377/5156549).
Also, looking at this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10420), you might have to use a polyfill.